# How to validate 2 form request in the same controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-formrequest

I am validating a credit card, for which I created two form requests:

`php artisan make:request StoreAmexRequest`
`php artisan make:request StoreVisaRequest`

How can I use them in the same controller?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{  

    if ($request->credit_card['number'][0] == 3) {

       new StoreAmexRequest(),

    }
    if ($request->credit_card['number'][0] == 4) {

       new StoreVisaRequest(),

        ]);

    }}
```

My code doesn't work, the $request variable doesn't receive the `StoreAmexRequest()`.

I am creating a credit card validator, the AMEX card validator is different from VISA cards, since AMEX is 15 digits and the CVV is 4 digits, and in VISA it is 16 digits.

It is necessary to use php artisan make:request since it is for an API that returns the response in JSON?

`\app\Http\Requests\StoreAmexRequest`:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    $year = date('Y');

    return [
        'credit_card.name' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'credit_card.number' => ['bail', 'required', 'min:15', 'max:16', new CredirCardRule],
        'credit_card.expiration_month' => ['required', 'digits:2'],
        'credit_card.expiration_year' => ['required', 'integer', 'digits:4', "min:$year"],
        'credit_card.cvv' => ['required', 'integer', 'digits_between:3,4']
    ];
}
public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
        $validator->errors(), 
    ]));
}
```

Comment: try passing the all request data into those class `$amexData = new StoreAmexRequest( $request->all() )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a single form request that validates both.

```php
public function store(StoreCreditCardRequest $request)
{
    YourCreditCardModel::create($request->validated());
}
```

And split the rules inside the form request

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    if ( $this->credit_card['number'][0] == 3 ) {
        return $this->amexRules();
    }

    if ( $this->credit_card['number'][0] == 4 ) {
        return $this->visaRules();
    }
}

protected function amexRules(): array
{
    return [
        // your validation rules for amex cards
    ];
}

protected function visaRules(): array
{
    return [
        // your validation rules for visa cards
    ];
}
```